# Как осуществить фильтрацию данных по датам?

Tags: база-данных, qt, sqlite, дата, qsqltablemodel

Имеется `QSqlTableModel`, `QTableView`, модуль - `QSQLITE`. Есть колонка `"Дата рождения"`. В ней занесены данные в формате `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Нужно по нажатию кнопки вывести записи, где возраст `> 30`. Я новичок и не понимаю как это можно сделать. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Отнять от текущей даты 30 лет и сравнить со значением в таблице.

Comment: Это да, есть трудности с реализацией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сначала в документацию по sqlite по [типам данных](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) и затем в документацию qt [QSqlTableModel::setFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter)

и теперь можно сделать:

```
model->setFilter('date(birthday) <= date(current_date, \'-30 years\')');
```

Comment: Это работает, если Дата рождения переименовать на birthday. Можно ли вписать кириллицу?

Comment: Если поле называется на кириллице, можно его писать как [Дата рождения], хотя лучше поля кириллицей не называть, чтобы не было проблем с кодировками и т.п.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомиться как работать с датами в `Sqlite` можно вот [тут](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-date-function/)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(birthday) <= date('now', '-30 years')
```

Здесь поле `birthday` должно быть строкой в формате `YYYY-MM-DD`